# JMeter - How User Agent works?

Tags: performance, jmeter, automated-tests, load, stress-testing

Using Blaze Meter extension in Chrome Browser - I have saved the .jmx of a website and used that file in my JMeter test. Where it creates HTTP Header Manager with below user agent.

User Agent - Mozilla/5.0 (Operating_system; Intel xxx OS XXX xxx_xxx_xxx) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36

Question: Since, the agent contains driver for (Mozilla, Chrome, Safari) which browser my test will run? How does it understand my browser details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent#Chrome_UA_string):

> The Chrome (or Chromium/blink-based engines) user agent string is similar to the Firefox format. For compatibility, it adds strings like "KHTML, like Gecko" and "Safari".
>
> ```
> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
> ```

So in your case the server will think that the virtual user is connecting from [MacOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) operating system and using [Chrome browser](https://www.google.com/chrome/) (or derivative)

You might want to parameterize this [`User-Agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header value to represent different users using different browsers. Also pay attention to other headers, i.e. [`Accept-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) as it has [huge impact on the data size](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) which is requested from the server, i.e. whether it will be compressed or not.

Comment: Thanks a-lot for your input. Got some real good understanding